# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET While accessing Firebase.com and all firebase apps

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome

A few days ago I tried accessing a site: guides.emberjs.com
It is run on the firebase.com platform.
I was able to access this site before.
Now I get this error: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
Can't access any firebase sites/apps.
It happens across all browsers on my laptop.
When accessing the site by mobile phone on the same WiFi connection I can access the site.
I have done everything outlined [here](http://www.toppctech.com/err-connection-reset-fixed/).

Would love for some help. Thanks

Comment: I've similar issue. Firebase sites are opening only when Fiddler is running. If Fiddler is closed I get Connection Reset error. Have you accessed your sites through Fiddler in the past? Link to my question: http://superuser.com/questions/1119237/firebase-com-is-not-opening-in-chrome-and-ie-without-fiddler

Comment: This is so weird! Why does this happen. I installed Fiddler and set it to view traffic only from chrome. I tried to connect to firebase.com but it wouldn't work. Then I clicked on the button to open the site in Internet Explorer and for some reason now I can go to firebase.com...